How to make a collection's custom property animatable?
As far as I understand, custom property in UI, is nothing more than an "add-on" written in python. But for some reason collection's custom property cannot be animated.
Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?



Hello. This looks like either a bug or an oversight because every single other instance (AFAICT) of custom properties accessible with UI is animatable.

@Gorgious, So it works (doesn't work) the same way for you? So as I understand it, there is no way for me to fix it?
Then where should I write about it?
Apparently it has something to do with the fact that this is a collection, and blender by default prohibits animating all the properties of the collection.
For example, there is a post (https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/VMfbbc/?sorting=hot) about the ability to animate the "disable in render" property of collections. I realize that there may be pitfalls that make this feature forbidden, but it's still a very strange decision.

Yes I'm sure there is a technical reason why it not possible, but the limitation affects everyone. You can report it to the devs from within Blender (Help> Report a bug) but I don't think they will consider it a bug. Although we might have a first hand explanation by an actual dev of why animation is not supported on collections

That's not possible at the moment. I talked to the core developer of blender. He didn't give the exact reason why, but they have no plans to change it.
Here's the link: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/120356
